# WordPress performance

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance

There's a wordpress project which has created with lots of bugs and now i have to cover up the previous programmer's job. Now the biggest problem is the performance issue.

The project is responding sometimes good and sometimes very poor on test cloud server with 4GB RAM, 4 CPU CORE, 4 MySQL CPU Core and support for 20 concurrent connections.

I just checked the server and it works fine. The response time for most of files are ok , but when database interaction is needed the performance is so poor.

I checked the database, i just saw 2 things that i thought might be a problem, but i'm not sure if i change these my problem would be solved:

1) some tables are InnoDB and some are MyISAM shouldn't all be the same? If ye which is correct for the performance?

2) the encoding is utf8_general_ci shouldn't be utf8_unicode_ci?

3) what if i re index all tables fileds using phpmyadmin by hand?

is any other thing that i have to consider?

Comment: Have you enabled and checked the slow query log?

Comment: remove revisions from wp_posts table which are not important. Also check the WP_query loop.

Comment: the thing that may stick is obviously the 20 connections, under normal use you'd be unlucky if 20 users started off together but I had a issue a couple a weeks ago where spambots were inserting comments for draft and using resources, they got in 40k before i plugged it. Check cpanel or equiv for connnections when slow.  Also what is the size of the database? Other things to watch out for are a lot of plugins enabled, which load every time. check out https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a codecanyon plugin I used "Fancy Designer" which serialised and attached a big js canvas + all client side uploaded images as a post meta to each woocommerce post and also this huge data was redundantly being saved to wp_options as woocommerce persistentcart data. I changed the plugin code to save everything as a file instead of database then my 30mb database which had just 2 orders inside is now just 4mb with 100 orders.